# How to display post and related comments on single page?

Tags: python, django

I am unable to design a code to render one particular post and it's related comments. The issue is maybe in views.py or the url.

I have looked at multiple sources without any results. I am a novice to coding and feel like I am missing some essential point. Posts and comments are getting created correctly and all comments get the correct post_id assigned.

My models.py is set up like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
content = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-home')

class Comment(models.Model):
cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
comment = models.TextField()
comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.comment


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-home')
```

My views.py is set up like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comment_list'] = Comment.objects.filter(post=WHAT SHOULD GO HERE?)
    return context
```

I need to pass the Post.id or primary key of the post in the filter above. Can someone explain what it should be?

The url used to access the post detail is as follows:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')
```

I get the post detail view rendered out as the author, title and content of the post when I have the following in views.py:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
```

The template for that is as below:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content%}
 
<article class="media content-section">
  <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{object.author.profile.image.url}}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y P e" }}</small>
        {% if object.author == user %}
        <div><a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id%}">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id%}">Delete</a></div>
        
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
{% for comment in comment_list %}
<div class='article-content'>
 <p>{{comment}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
 
{% endblock %}
```

How should I take the post.id or pk of the Post and use it to filter the comments related only to that particular post?

Also, what is a good way to set up a template for rendering the queryset?

Comment: First, Your class is returning `PostComment`s and your `get_queryset()` is returning a `queryset` of `Post`s, so calling `object` on your template won't work, since there is no such thing.

Comment: Got you! Is there any tutorial link where I can learn how one single post and it's related comments can be rendered out starting with having the primary_key for the post?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to iterate over the reverse link from `Post` object to the `Comment` objects linked to it (by default as `comment_set`) in your template:

```
{% for comment in post.comment_set %}
```

If you want greater control you inject a queryset into the context, something like this, to get the most recent six comments only.

```
"comments": post.comment_set.order_by("-comment_date")[:6]
```

The post object selected should be available as `self.object` in a `DetailView` and will be default be injected into the render context as `object`. An invaluable resource for navigating the structure of Django Class-based views is the [Classy CBV](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)
site.

Warning: this is "off the top of my head" so don't assume it's all perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A single object will have access to its related objects.
Try this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    # There's no need to define get_context_data() here
```

Now your template will have the post available as `post` (and also `object`).
All of the comments that have this `post` are available on the template like this:

```
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
    <div class='article-content'>
        <p>{{ comment }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```